# Returning an error message when typed a wrong spelling in input box

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net, vba

I have this code which I used VBA to insert, update and delete data in mySQL database. I have an input box to search a specific data in SQL table using their number, when I type the number and when there is matched record the program says "Record found". but the program errors everytime I type a number and has no matched data. My question is that, how will I return an error message that says "No Record found" when there is no matched data?. I am learning vba as a beginner and some codes used were not really familiar to me.. Thanks.

```
  Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
myConn
Dim holdstr As String
holdstr = InputBox("Enter name")
If holdstr = "" Then
MsgBox "Please fill up the requirements", vbInformation, "Message"
conn.Close
Exit Sub
End If
rs.Open "SELECT * FROM lemployees where ENumber = '" & holdstr & "'", conn

MsgBox "Record found!", vbInformation, "Message"

UserForm2.TextBox2.Text = rs!ELName
```

Comment: Test the value of `rs.EOF` after you call rs.Open

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is check the Recordset RecordCount property after you have opened it.

```
Dim rcCount As Integer
rs.Open "SELECT * FROM lemployees where ENumber = '" & holdstr & "'", conn
rcCount = rs.RecordCount
If rcRecordCount = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No Record found", vbInformation, "Message"
Else
    MsgBox "Record found!", vbInformation, "Message"
    UserForm2.TextBox2.Text = rs!ELName
End If
```

Comment: BTW, if you noticed, I used a variable, rcCount, instead simply using the rs.RecordCount property for the "If" test. In the case of VB, this is really not necessary. However, it a good habit to form. This is because you are certain that the code to load the variable is going to be executed only once and, when it is referenced later, you are sure is stored locally. If this doesn't make sense, don't worry. Just form the habit of using local variable for If and For Each loops, etc.

Comment: @Jakester26..I have tried the code u gave, and it still says "No record found" eventhough I put a correct number. Where could I possibly insert your code?. maybe it doens't functions well because I inserted it incorrect..

Comment: You are assigning the number of records to one variable (rcCount) and considering in the If statement a different one (rcRecordCount).

Comment: Answers are greatly appreciated :D

Comment: @user2123999 - did you try testing the value of `rs.EOF` ?  If no records are returned this will be `True`